# mount point for swap not needed

Tags: swap

Why do we say that swap partition does not need a mount point? is it because swap is basically for virtual memory access and we don't need to view or access it so there is no need to mount it? or is it done automatically maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, a swap space is there so that inactive memory pages get written to disk (and reread when they are used again). It makes no sense to mount a swap partition.

However, with Linux at least, you still need to declare it in your fstab: the boot process will then activate it using `swapon`.